# Include OCaml library with dune

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune

I'm trying to make an OCaml program that uses the Str library

I'm using dune for compiling

My Makefile is

```
dune build src/myProgram.exe
```

My dune textfile in the `src` folder is

```
(env (_ (flags :standard -w -27-26-32-33)))
(executable (name myProgram) (modules myProgram) (libraries myLib) (modes byte exe))  
(library (name myLib) (modules M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 M6 M7))
```

My bash error message is :

```
File "_none_", line 1:  
Error: No implementations provided for the following modules:  
         Str referenced from src/.myProgram.eobjs/native/dune__exe__myProgram.cmx
```

I don't know how to include this Str library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it into an answer, tool want to list `str` as a library.

```
(executable 
  (name myProgram) 
  (modules myProgram) 
  (libraries str myLib) 
  (modes byte exe))
```